# Newbie in Css. Can't get to duplicate a tutorial about CSS animation of a frog

Tags: css, animation

This is kind of embarassing for me, but I have a final project for my Software engineering class, and I'd been searching for tutorials so I can see and learn about html css and javascript to implement it in my project. I never worked on those, so I found a cool tutorial about some animation that I wanted to implement in my project so I decided to give it a try, and I cant get the code to work.
Here's the tutorial link.
http://davidwalsh.name/logo-animation

Here's my code (http://jsfiddle.net/5x4wv/):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
    <div class="mike">
  <div class="head">
    <div class="eyes">
      <div class="eye">
        <div class="pupil"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="eye">
        <div class="pupil"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nose">
      <div class="ball"></div>
      <div class="ball"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mouth"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mike {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 2%;
  transition: all 1s;
}

.mike:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5) rotate(360deg);
}

.head {
  width: 195px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #92ae57;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 103px;
}

.eyes {
  width:200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 45px;
}

.eye {
  width: 95px;
  height: 93px;
  background-color: #ffe13b;
  border: 10px solid #92ae57;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 2;
  animation: eyes 5s infinite step-start 0s;
}

.eye:last-child {
  float:right;
}

.pupil {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border: 10px solid #353535;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 38px;
  margin-left:27px;  
  z-index: 3;
  animation: pupil 5s infinite step-start 0s;
}

.pupil:last-child{
  float:right;
}

.ball {
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border: 5px solid #6f8346;
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  left: 88px;
}

.ball:last-child {
  float:left;
  margin-left: 14px;
}

.mouth {
  height: 100px;
  width: 180px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #6f8346;
  position: relative;
  top: 8px;
  left: 7px;
}

/* Animations */

@keyframes eyes {
   0%, 100% {
    background: #92ae57;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid #92ae57;
  } 

   5%, 95% {  
    background:#ffe13b;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 10px solid #92ae57;
  }
}

@keyframes pupil {
  0%, 100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  5%, 95% {
    opacity: 1;
 }
}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using Sublimetext 2 and running in Chrome.

Comment: Please create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) out of your code. That'll improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: i can teach you for realz...but it's so broad

Comment: You have to add vendor-prefixes to the `animation` and `transform` properties (`-webkit-` for Chrome): http://jsfiddle.net/5x4wv/1/

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, but thank you guys it worked perfectly. I just had to add the vendor specifications :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefix stuff...

Delay duration only delays animation at first start not at every iteration.

USE FLOATS BARELY...use relative position especially for this..

http://jsfiddle.net/T862G/ **take a look it works**

```
@-webkit-keyframes eyes {

    10% {background-color:#92ae57;}
    25% {background-color:#ffe13b;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes pupil {
    10% {opacity: 0;}
    25% {opacity: 1;}
}

.mike:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(1.5);
}
```